# CentOS 4.7: Failure to execute YUM UPDATE command

Tags: centos

While attempting to update my CentOS 4.7 server, the YUM UPDATE command returns:

- not using ftp, http[s], or file for repos, skipping - Invalid repo/release/arch combination
- long URL for update ending in repomd.xml gives 404
- no more mirrors to try

I saw on another post like this (CentOS 5.x though) with an answer about support being ended at some date in 2017 meaning a different URL is needed to find updated files.

Is this true for 4.7? It makes sense that it would be if this is the standard way Linux is managed on the distributors' side.   If so, are there other sites to find the repomd.xml file seemingly needed for an update?

All of this started from a failed YUM INSTALL SQL command.

Last, does the update command change the version of my installation or just add/modify files in my version to the ones included in newer versions?  The latter is how I imagine it working but I'm pretty new to Linux and want to know everything I can reasonably.

Comment: Why bother to `yum update` CentOS 4.7? It doesn't get updates anymore. Upgrade to a supported system.

Comment: Do you mean CentOS 7.4?

Comment: I meant to write 4.7.  I am using it because I have only one physical server to use for my project and 4.7 works on it.  It's something I want to do this way and don't want to change.  Why do you say to upgrade with no reason why?

Comment: @Christian The reason is simple: 4.x is *unsupported* and is end of life. 4.x does not receive updates. The only supported releases are here: https://wiki.centos.org/About/Product/ - Based on your post history, sure your hardware is old (PowerEdge 2900), but it is not old enough that it can't run at least CentOS 7. In fact, based on dell's documentation, 6 is supported. I bet you could run 7, granted that you update your BIOS to full (latest is 2.7.0 for your hardware). The backplane and firmware for other pieces have updates also.

Answer (score 1):

Other commenters are wondering why you bother updating this OS and whether it's 7.4 you meant because, in terms of Linux OS recency, CentOS 4.7 is a very, very, extremely old operating system.

CentOS 4 was released back in 2005, with *any* updates ending in the year 2012.

The reason to upgrade (aside from the obvious absence of a maintained repo) would be simply because it would have reduced connectivity to other machines on the Internet. This is due to SSL/TLS encryption, which received many updates throughout these years. So if those "other" up-to-date servers you're connecting to from the ancient machine, enforce, e.g. TLS 1.1, you might be out of luck connecting to them in the first place.

That said you can try your luck with the [CentOS Vault](http://vault.centos.org/4.7/) and point the repos there. It's not encrypted, so your chances of being able to install packages are high :).

You'll need to adjust repo definitions at `/etc/yum.repos.d/` and point them to the right corresponding vault repo, e.g. `http://vault.centos.org/4.7/updates/x86_64/` (if the machine/OS is x86_64 arch).

Comment: Now THERE'S an answer.  I see and receive way too many answers on forums saying "just do X" and it so not helpful.  Tanks for the reasoning behind it.  I may get a newer server that can support 7 or run it through a VM for setup and learning before using it the way I want.

Comment: Why not at least 4.9?  I mean it’s still horribly insecure and out of date but at least it’s the latest ancient version of 4.x.